# use a page to render 1 post and include comments FOR THE POST

Tags: comments, page-template

wordpress 3.3.2
hi. so i have this custom post type and i use a page to show just one post.
url.td/page/

the page renders the post but now i want to include comments.
if i allow comments for the page, the comments get assigned to the page, but i want it to get assigned to the post, for example
url.td/page/my-post

if i disallow comments, the comments form is hidden.

this is my page

```
get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary">
    <div id="content" role="main">
        <?php
            $args = array( 'post_type' => 'charts', 'posts_per_page' => 1 );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                get_template_part( 'content', 'charts' );
            endwhile;
        ?>
    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

and here comes my content-charts.php

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

lots of stuff here...

<?php 
    wp_reset_query();
    comments_template( '', true );
?>
</article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
```

so i thought, if the comments form is inside the post, it will be related to it, but it aint..

Answer (score 0):

untested - 
try and remove the `wp_reset_query();` from content-charts.php;
add `wp_reset_postdata();` after the `endwhile;` into your page template.

Comment: nope, that didnt work. have a solution now, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

trail and error, right?

here is my dirty solution. 
in my content file i just recall the whole loop.

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'charts', 'posts_per_page' => 1 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    comments_template( '', true );
endwhile;
```